# Reading a text/CSV file from multiple applications at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, file, io

Is it possible to read(not write) a CSV file from multiple process(c# apps or SQL procedures or any other jobs) at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Yes..... next question?

Comment: @paqogomez That makes it hard for me to write my answer as "Yes" without looking like I copied your comment ;)

Comment: I found similar question/answer along with "write" and "lock" but not specific to "Read".  Thanks much!!

Comment: Glad you did your searching.  Please try to do that before posting.  Also, it would help if you show what you've tried as well.  SO is not a "write this thing for me" kind of site.

Comment: such answers are easy for someone and difficult for someone !! :)  Thanks Again !

Comment: @Yogesh If you have trouble reading the same file from multiple processes please show us your code and we'll help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as long as the readers open the CSV non-exclusively, for example:

```
var csvStream = new FileStream(csvfileName, FileMode.Open, 
                          FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```